# Dell OS10 equivalent of Cisco switchport access

Tags: cisco, vlan, dell

hoping someone knows OS10 command structure :)

In the Cisco world, if I want to create an access port and add it to VLAN 50 its simply:

```
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 50
```

What would the equivalent be on a switch running OS10?

Comment: Please accept an answer if it answered your question. And you may vote for useful answers, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
switchport access vlan <VLID>
```

should work (requires `interface` context).